# Undefined method 'questions'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have three models: posts, questions and comments (comments belong to questions  and questions belong to posts) and am trying to show the last 2 questions on the comments index page.
Here is my comments_index function:

```
def index

@question = Question.find params[:question_id]
@comments = @question.comments
@questions = @comment.questions.order(:created_at).limit(2).reverse_order

end
```

and my comments_index:

```
<% @questions.each do |question| %>
<%= question.body %>
<% end %>
```

Here is the error i am getting:

```
 undefined method `questions' for nil:NilClass
```

My routes.rb file looks like this:

```
 resources :posts do
  resources :questions do
  end
 end

 resources :questions do
  resources :comments do
  end
 end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question has_many comments?
Comment belongs_to question?

If that's the case, you will only be able to get the comment's 1 question... but you're already getting that when you go to the question page... If you're just trying to get the last 2 questions asked (period), you can do:

```
@post = @question.post
@questions = @post.questions.order(:created_at).last(2)
```

That will get you the last 2 questions in the database.

and your routes... shouldn't it be:

```
resources :posts do
  resources :questions do
    resources :comments do
    end
  end
end
```

?

Comment: Thanks that works except i want it to be the last 2 questions belonging to the post. Sorry if i wasn't clear enough. I think you're right about my routes, i'll change that.

Comment: so... `@question.post.questions.order(:created_at).last(2)`.  Might even want to grab `@post` as an instance variable to use in the view? so... `@post = @question.post`.  then `@post.questions` etc

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo. you are initializing `@comment`s but using `@comment`

```
def index 
  @question = Question.find params[:question_id]
  @comments = @question.comments
  @questions = @comments.collect{|c|c.questions.order(:created_at).limit(2).reverse_order}
end
```

Since comments is a collection, you would want to get the last 2 questions from each comment

Comment: Hmm, that doesn't seem to display anything.